# Does Debian 9 (Stretch) have a new updating mechanism?

Tags: debian

My Stretch system informed me this morning that there were several updates available and gave me the option to "Restart & Update". I think in the past, it was always Update, then Restart. So I clicked Ok, and the system restarted, then updated a bunch of packages (using a status screen I haven't seen before), then restarted again like normal. Is there a name for this feature/behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

This mechanism is provided by [GNOME Software](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software) in combination with PackageKit; see the [design document](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/SoftwareUpdates) too.

You don’t have to use it, you can still use Synaptic, `apt` etc.

Comment: thanks, the design document lead me to what I was looking for, it seems to actually be a systemd thing called "offline-updates" that I was curious about

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.offline-updates.7.en.html